# Spring application without web.xml log4j configuration

Tags: spring, jersey, log4j, log4j2

I have a Spring + Jersey web application that I'm migrating from a web.xml to annotation base configuration. I'm implementing WebApplicationInitializer and everything works except log4j, because I have a custom file name.

In the web.xml I had

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/custom-name-log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This worked.

Now, I tried to do the same in Java:

```
container.setInitParameter("log4jConfiguration", "/WEB-INF/custom-name-log4j.xml");
```

This doesn't work... I get the following errors in Tomcat 7.0.62:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j context configuration provided. This is very unusual.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

My WAR file contains the xml in the WEB-INF/ folder.

Do I have to do more than specifying that log4jConfiguration parameter?

Later Edit:
WebApplicationInitializer

```
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(MyApplicationConfiguration.class);

        container.setInitParameter("log4jConfiguration", "/WEB-INF/custom-name-log4j.xml");

        rootContext.setConfigLocation("my.package.spring");

        final FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncodingFilter = container.addFilter("characterEncodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        characterEncodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");

        container.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.default", "prod");

        rootContext.register(SecurityContextFilter.class);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        container.addListener(new RequestContextListener());

        container.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "");

        final ServletContainer servlet = new ServletContainer();
        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = container.addServlet("appServlet", servlet);
        appServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "my.package");
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        final Set<String> mappingConflicts = appServlet.addMapping("/rest/*");

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to register a Listener : `Log4jConfigListener` (you can find it in org.springframework.web.util)

```
servletContext.addListener(Log4jConfigListener.class);
```

By the way, you can note that it is [deprecated since spring 4.2.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html)

**EDIT**

Sorry I didn't realized that you were using log4j**2**,
everything stated above is false, and here is the solution for you :

log4j2 (thanks to `log4j-web` artifact) & spring are both relying on `ServletContainerInitializer` from `servlet 3.0` API to setup the `ServletContext`.
The problem is that the order they are executed depends on the order they are scanned on the classpath and you can't really rely on it (in your case the `Log4jServletContainerInitializer` startup methods is called before the one from `SpringServletContainerInitializer`).

To correct this you can declare your own `ServletContainerInitializer` implementation which we'll be taken into account before others (before scanning the classpath) and here is a sample :

```
public class Log4j2ConfigServletContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {
        ctx.setInitParameter("log4jConfiguration", "/WEB-INF/custom-name-log4j.xml");
    }
}
```

Then you have to create a file :
`/META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`

and put into it :

`example.initializer.Log4j2ConfigServletContainerInitializer`
(change to suit your needs)

and the configuration you provided to set a custom log4j config file location will be set before triggering the `Log4jServletContainerInitializer` and everything is going to be fine.

see :

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/using-annotations.html#servlet-container-initializers

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html

**EDIT**

POC @ http://www.filedropper.com/32713596_1
just run `mvn jetty:run`

Comment: I added the listener, still not working. The weird thing is that I get the 2 errors before WebApplicationInitializer.onStartup

Comment: Something else might be wrong, can you post us your `WebApplicationInitializer` implementation with your question ?

Comment: Added WebApplicationInitializer

Comment: I just edited my answer for you, plus took the permission to add the `log4j2` tag to your question

Comment: It still doesn't work. I added Log4j2ConfigServletContainerInitializer and I can see with debug that it's called BEFORE my WebApplicationInitializer. But still no logging. I tried adding a file, log4j2.xml in my WAR's classpath and logging is working. So maybe log4jConfiguration property doesn't work?

Comment: I'm 100% that `log4jConfiguration` is still working with log4j2, have a look at `Log4jWebInitializerImpl`. I uploaded a POC for you